# ( Flutter and Mac ) Possible to create a new project to upgrade an existing app?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have an app in production, all worked good, but after apple forced to upgrade Xcode to run the app I started to face some issues and no one has found the solution to it yet, my business is in trouble because of this and I need a quick solution to it.

I have a question ( for mac/appstore context):

I succeeded to get around my run issue by creating a new project. I would like to know if there is a way using which I can link this new flutter project to older projet who contain the app which is in production and create a new release?

I think it needs to have the same

- Bundle name
- Bundle identifier signing certificate
- Also perhaps older
  archives from original project etc

All these things tell me it's not possible :( but perhaps I'm wrong

Comment: Keeping the same bundle name and bundle identifier should have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest saving the project in version control,
delete the current `macos` and `build` folder and regenerate it with `flutter create .` Then you can add back the code and config you had before in xcode.
This way you will keep your current flutter project but with a new xcode macos project.

Before that, you might wanna try if calling `flutter clean` solves this problem.
It also cleans the Xcode project.

For keeping the app you just need to have the same bundle id and a valid signing certificate. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/39216

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to create a new project.

All you have to do is delete the relevant config for the platform.

In the case of ios development, you can simply `rm -rf ios`
In the case of android development, you can simply `rm -rf android`

Be sure to upgrade `Xcode` &  `flutter upgrade` and navigate to the project and run `flutter create .`

Then you can build again.
`flutter build ios`

You can do `flutter clean` to be sure that you don't leave anything behind or just get rid of the `build`.

This will reinitialize the platform specifics you are missing.

After that, you can port back the `ios` and/or `android` specific configurations such as bundle id and certificates.

Note: Please take a backup of the project (git would be better). Just make a new branch for the new version `git checkout -b v2`.